# How can I access the function applied in success of an $http.post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-factory

I have this function triggered when I click a button.

```
.controller('Formctrl', function($scope, ichrisLayoutLeavebalanceService){
    $scope.listRowSelected = function (list, item) {   
       var det = { detnumber: item.detnumber };
       ichrisLayoutLeavebalanceService.callPost(det).success(function (data){ ichrisLayoutLeavebalanceService.leaveBalanceProcess(); });
    };
});
```

However, it seems like I can't access the leaveBalanceProcess(). It seems like only the factory part is enabled to be shared. Here's my controller and factory code that is access by the code above.

```
.directive(/*code... code...*/{/*code... long code...*/
   /*code... code...*/},
   controller : ($scope, ichrisLayoutLeavebalanceService) {

     function par(){
     //code... code...
     }
     $scope.leaveBalanceProcess = function (){/*codes... codes... */}

     $scope.build = function () {
         ichrisLayoutLeavebalanceService.callPost(par()).success(function (data) { $scope.leaveBalanceProcess(data) });
     }

     $scope.build();
   }
})
.factory('ichrisLayoutLeavebalanceService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var leaveBalanceService = {};

    leaveBalanceService.callPost = function (par) {
        return $http.post('/api/values/entries/LeaveBalanceEntries', par);
    }

    return leaveBalanceService;
```

}]);

So now how can I acces the whole controller?

Comment: You have to use ichrisLayoutLeavebalanceService.callPost() because in the factory you return the leaveBalanceService object

Comment: Yes and as you can see I've used it. I actually also debug it and the call works. However the only factory part which is this one

$http.post('/api/values/entries/LeaveBalanceEntries', par). What I need is to access as well as the the success and its function.

.success(function (data) { $scope.leaveBalanceProcess(data) });

Comment: must work, try to write a simple plunkr

Comment: I dont see how it could work, in the success function you are invoking a ichrisLayoutLeavebalanceService.leaveBalanceProcess() not defined at ichrisLayoutLeavebalanceService factory.